# Wrap jQuery ajax call in variable so i can setTimeout and clearTimeout when needed?

Tags: ajax, jquery, settimeout

Is there a way i can put a jQuery ajax call inside of a variable so i can create a setTimeout for specific events and clearTimeout for specific events? for example if this makes any sense something like this:

```
var testEvent = function(){ $(this).load("info.php"); };
```

**On specific event**

```
setTimeout("testEvent()",3000);
```

**On another specific event**

```
clearTimeout("testEvent()");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a couple of nifty plugin functions to do the trick?

```
$.fn.loadLater = function (url, time) {
    var me = this;
    this.data('load-later-timer', setTimeout(function () {
        me.load(url);
    }, time));
};

$.fn.dontLoadLater = function () {
    var timer = this.data('load-later-timer');
    if (timer != null) clearTimeout(timer);
};
```

Use like so:

```
// Start timer
$(this).loadLater('info.php', 3000);

// Stop timer
$(this).dontLoadLater();
```

Comment: wow! amazing! that actually solved a couple other issues i was having, thanks a million, those are some super nifty plugins! thanks so much seriously, can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 2):

This absolutely makes sense, just do like this:

```
var id = setTimeout(function() {testEvent()}, 3000);

clearTimeout(id);
```

Make sure to keep `id` accessible for both event handlers.

EDIT: I've overseen that you're referring to `this` inside the `testEvent`. Assuming that `this` is some node you're locating using jQuery, the code may look like this:

```
var id = setTimeout(function() {
   $('.your-selector').each(testEvent);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: ah, thanks so much, so how do i call the timed event then, do i just write var id = setTimeout....... whenever i need it to be called?

Comment: right, but make sure you keep the timer id (the `id` variable) if you're going to stop the timer, otherwise you may do simply `setTimeout(function() {testEvent()}, 3000)` .